# How to make button enabled or disabled when there's a checked row in table in Datatable.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

My code makes button enabled when some rows in table is checked and disabled when no row is checked. (datatables.js has define pagination right?).

My problem is on the 1st page: it works fine, when I checked or unchecked any row, the button enables and disables just as what I want. But on other pages other than page 1, when I check or uncheck any row. There's nothing happenning on the button. It stays disabled. How can I fix it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#user-list-departments-selectAll').click(function(e) {
        $('table[id=dataTable]').find('td input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
        var countchecked = $("#dataTable input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
        if (countchecked > 0) {
            $('button[id=btn-manage-privillege]').attr("disabled", false);
            $('button[id=btn-manage-account]').attr("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $('button[id=btn-manage-privillege]').attr("disabled", true);
            $('button[id=btn-manage-account]').attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });

    $('table[id=dataTable]').find('td input:checkbox').click(function(e) {
        $('#user-list-departments-selectAll').prop('checked', false);
        var countchecked = $("#dataTable input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
        if (countchecked > 0) {
            $('button[id=btn-manage-privillege]').attr("disabled", false);
            $('button[id=btn-manage-account]').attr("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $('button[id=btn-manage-privillege]').attr("disabled", true);
            $('button[id=btn-manage-account]').attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Are you using [select extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/)? You could use [select/deselect event](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/integration#Events) then. Note that once you reload the page, you have different checkboxes that the ones you assigned click listeners to.

Comment: i dont know want d you mean because i use datatable.js for first time. but you gave me an idea about select events. thank you..

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html i search this and this may solve my problem

Comment: thanks. you answered my quistion in simple way